# Selecting a value from DROP DOWN List, where the values are hidden

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a search button inside a drop down list.

I want to click on Search Icon and select some value from the drop down list displayed, using Mouse.

This is My code-

1. ID of DropDown

   `WebElement objSpanElement = driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath(".//*[@id='cboCargoReleases_TabCargoRelease_CustomerID']"));`
2. This is a class that Dropdown list belongs too `'objSpanElement.findElement(By.className("clsOWPAComboBox_Style_TextBox")).clear();'`
3. This is search button id

   'objSpanElement.findElement(By.className("clsOWPAComboBox_Style_DropDownButton_Search")).click();`

The Value of drop down list is in table and this is how it looks when we see the code behind it

```
<div class="clsOWPAComboBox_Style_DropDownList" style="position: absolute;   top: 447px; left: 353px; overflow: auto; visibility: visible; height: 150px;   width: 207px; z-index: 100;">
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="clsOWPAComboBox_Style_DropDownListItem_MouseOver"    nowrap="">005203 - GLOBAL METAL INC</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The Value of drop down list is in table and this is how it looks when we see the code behind it
<div class="clsOWPAComboBox_Style_DropDownList" style="position: absolute; top: 447px; left: 353px; overflow: auto; visibility: visible; height: 150px; width: 207px; z-index: 100;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="clsOWPAComboBox_Style_DropDownListItem_MouseOver" nowrap="">005203 - GLOBAL METAL INC</td>
</tr>